# standalone version of folly::Synchronized

Tags: c++, thread-safety, folly

Is there a functional equivalent of https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/docs/Synchronized.md that is self-contained and preferably header only so I don't have to pull in entire folly library into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dicussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/p132c7/a_c_locking_wrapper/) where `folly::Synchronized` also has been mentioned and some other solutions are provided.

Probably you're searching for something like this: https://github.com/copperspice/cs_libguarded

A snippet of there [test code](https://github.com/copperspice/cs_libguarded/blob/master/test/test_shared.cpp):

```
shared_guarded<int, shared_mutex> data(0);
{
   auto data_handle = data.lock();
   
   ++(*data_handle);
   
   data_handle.reset();
   data_handle = data.lock();
}

auto data_handle = data.try_lock();
      
REQUIRE(data_handle != nullptr);
REQUIRE(*data_handle == 1);
```

Note: cs_libguarded requires C++17.